# Hiding and showing section in tableview upon a button request

Tags: swift, uitableview, button, uialertcontroller, sections

I have a tableview that has different sections. Upon loading the view I hide the section and create a overlay button over the section which upon clicking it it displays a alert box asking for admin password

**PROBLEM**: Now, I am trying to show the section that was initially hidden once the user inputs the right password and hide the button. **NEED HELP WITH THIS**

Initially setting the section 1 to be hidden and creating overlay button:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if section == 1 {

        let enableButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 320, y: 160), size: CGSize(width: 130, height: 30)))
        enableButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        enableButton.setTitle("Enable Section", for: .normal)
        enableButton.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        enableButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ConfigTableViewController.enableButtonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(enableButton)

        return 0
    }

    else if section == 2 {
        return 2
    }
    else if section == 3 {
        return 2
    }

    return 1
}
```

This func calls when the button is clicked:

```
func enableButtonClicked() {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Admin Password", message: "Please input admin password", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let enable = UIAlertAction(title: "Enable", style: .default) { (_) in
        let field = alertController.textFields?[0].text
        if let x = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "initial admin password"), x == field {


        }
        else{

            let wrongPwd = UIAlertController(title: "Wrong Admin Password", message: nil, preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            wrongPwd.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(wrongPwd, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (_) in }

    alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Admin Password"
        textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
    }

    alertController.addAction(enable)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what actually happens?

Comment: @Abizern: Initially when the app loads the section is hidden and there is button over it "Enable section" When I  click the button and input the admin password, I expect upon the right password the section becomes available and the "Enable section" button becomes hidden. Currently with the code what happens is that if I input the right password nothing happens (this is where I need help to reveal the section and hide the button) and if the user puts the wrong admin password, it put an alert saying "Wrong password"

Comment: I can't see anything in your section code that changes what is displayed if the user is successfully logged in.

Comment: @Abizern: Below is the part where the user is successfully logged in. I need help in this part. How to make the section visible and made the button hidden? 

    if let x = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "initial admin password"), x == field {


        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem , i will  suggest you to create a `flag` which check whether your `PassWord` is correct or not.

1.Suppose you have a flag :

```
var correctPasswordFlag : Bool = false // initially assume it wrong
```

2. Simply Drag a button to your cell and create `IBOutlet` say `configEnableButton` and add Target Selector to this Method :

   func enableButtonClicked() {

   ```
       let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Admin Password", message: "Please input admin password", preferredStyle: .alert)

       let enable = UIAlertAction(title: "Enable", style: .default) { (_) in
           let field = alertController.textFields?[0].text
           if let x = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "initial admin password"), x == field {
              //For correct password
              correctPasswordFlag  = true
              //Reload Tableview
               configTableview.relaod() // if not then create iboutlet of tableview
           }
           else{
             //For wrong password
              correctPasswordFlag  = false
              //Reload Tableview
               configTableview.relaod() // if not then create iboutlet of tableview
               let wrongPwd = UIAlertController(title: "Wrong Admin Password", message: nil, preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
               wrongPwd.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
               self.present(wrongPwd, animated: true, completion: nil)
           }
       }

       let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (_) in }

       alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
           textField.placeholder = "Admin Password"
           textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
       }

       alertController.addAction(enable)
       alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

       self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
   ```

Hope this Helps you to fix your issue . **Enjoy coding and Keep Learning.**

Comment: It did. Thanks for your help.